# Trouble with scopes in LET and LET*

Tags: scope, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to implement a [local search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)) for optimization. I am very new to Lisp, so this is the code I came up with (notice the `FORMAT`s):

```
(defun local-search (solution)
  "Improve solutions by changing the order of the points"
  (flet ((improve (route)
           (alexandria:shuffle (copy-tree route))))
    (let ((best-solution solution)
          (best-cost (solution-cost solution)))
      (format t "~a~%~%" best-cost)
      (format t "Counter, Current, Best~%")
      (loop with counter = 0
         while (< counter *max_iterations*)
         do (let* ((new-solution (improve solution))
                   (new-cost (solution-cost new-solution)))
              (format t "~a, ~a, ~a~%" counter new-cost best-cost)
              (if (< new-cost best-cost)
                  (setf best-cost new-cost
                        best-solution new-solution
                        counter 0)
                  (incf counter)))
         finally (return best-solution)))))
```

Now, it may not be the most idiomatic way to do this, and I'm interested in finding better ways to implement this, but my main trouble is this: the `SETF`s don't seem to be updating my parameters. When I run my function, this is the output I get (`*max_iterations*` is set to 10):

```
796.4436

Counter, Current, Best
0, 796.4436, 796.4436
1, 796.4436, 796.4436
2, 796.4436, 796.4436
3, 796.4436, 796.4436
4, 796.4436, 796.4436
5, 796.4436, 796.4436
6, 796.4436, 796.4436
7, 796.44354, 796.4436
0, 796.4436, 796.44354
1, 796.4436, 796.44354
2, 796.4436, 796.44354
3, 796.4436, 796.44354
4, 796.4436, 796.44354
5, 796.4436, 796.44354
6, 796.4436, 796.44354
7, 796.44366, 796.44354
8, 796.4436, 796.44354
9, 796.4436, 796.44354
```

From the restarts in `counter`, I can see that the code has found better solutions, but it hasn't been able to `SETF` them. I suppose this is because of some scoping rules I'm not aware of. What am I missing?

### Edit

For context, this is the `solution-cost` function:

```
(defun solution-cost (solution)
  "Calculate the total cost of a solution"
  (reduce #'+ (mapcar #'cost solution)))

(defun cost (points &optional (acc 0))
  "Calculate the total cost of a route"
  (if (null points) acc
      (cost (cdr points)
            (+ acc (funcall *distance-fn* (first points) (second points))))))
```

The full code is [in this paste](http://paste.lisp.org/display/157458). This is how I'm calling it:

```
(improve (initial-population *n_plants* (random-points)))
```

Comment: There's only one binding of new-solution, and your SETF is affecting it (there's nothing else for it to change).  You could easily add some more output to show that you're setting the right variables.  I think your problem might be that you're always calling (improve solution) rather than (improve best-solution).

Comment: hm, I take that back, it still looks like alexandria:shuffle returns a random permutation, so that *might* not matter as much.  What does your SOLUTION-COST function look like?  Is it possible that it's returning very close values which are close enough that the 4 decimal places don't really tell the whole story?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: edited the question with `SOLUTION-COST`. The full code (it's not very big) is [in this paste](http://paste.lisp.org/display/157458).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: I would say such small variations in cost are rather unlikely. Also, I've run it several times now, and not once found the values not repeating.

Comment: What form are you calling?

Comment: Just edited again. It's `(improve (initial-population *n_plants* (random-points)))`

Comment: Looks like SETF isn't executed. Because it isn't. Or very rarely. Put a PROGN around the IF branch and print when it runs...

Comment: @RainerJoswig: it is very rare indeed (I have yet to come up with a better, more direct way to reach improvements in the cost function). But, when it does execute, you can see the variables aren't updated.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: true. Looks like JoshuaTaylor was right, it's just that the variations are too small.

Comment: How big is your `*n-plants*`?  Try to test with the smallest sensible number first.

Comment: @Svante good point, I had forgotten to tune that. Looks like making `*n_plants*` smaller makes little difference on the result. Making it substantially bigger makes much better solutions, though.

Comment: @Guilherme: I meant to test with something like 3 or 4, so that you can reconstruct and verify by hand that different solutions are tried.

Answer (score 2):

The update happens:

```
RRA-DARP 64 > (improve (initial-population *n_plants* (random-points)))
Was: 988.39277
Now is: 943.89106

Was: 943.89106
Now is: 895.5029

Was: 895.5029
Now is: 895.0123

900.5653

Counter, Current, Best
0, 900.56525, 900.5653 < old best

:SMALLER

0, 900.56525, 900.56525 < new best
1, 900.56525, 900.56525
2, 900.56525, 900.56525
3, 900.56525, 900.56525
4, 900.56525, 900.56525
5, 900.5653, 900.56525
6, 900.56525, 900.56525
7, 900.5653, 900.56525
8, 900.5653, 900.56525
9, 900.56525, 900.56525
Was: 895.0123
Now is: 900.56525

900.56525
```